# Broadcast one arbitrary element of __m128 vector

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, sse2

I need to broadcast one arbitrary element of __m128 vector. 
For example the second element:

```
__m128 a = {a0, a1, a2, a3};
__m128 b = {a1, a1, a1, a1};
```

I know that there are intrinsics _mm_set1_ps(float) and _mm_broadcast_ss(float*). 
But these intrinsics can load value from common use registers of memory. 
Is exist any way to set scalar value from another vector register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to see to  _mm_shuffle_epi32(). Its using will be easy with next helper function:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

template <int index> inline __m128 Broadcast(const __m128 & a)
{
    return _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_shuffle_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(a), index * 0x55));
}

int main()
{
    __m128 a = {a0, a1, a2, a3};
    __m128 b = Broadcast<1>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is that I want.

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `_mm_shuffle_ps` like this:

```
b = _mm_shuffle_ps(a, a, _MM_SHUFFLE(1,1,1,1));
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution gets the same results. I don't now which is the best.

Comment: @Alex usually this one, whenever there is a difference. Using wrongly typed instructions can cost an extra bypass delay, depending on the context and the µarch.

Comment: The disadvantage of this instruction is that it may require an additional register move (which however, may or may not have any impact at all)

Comment: @chtz I agree, somehow there is no `__m128` intrinsic for `pshufd`

Comment: okay after [some research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495363/why-is-there-no-floating-point-intrinsic-for-pshufd-instruction/) turns out this answer is the way to go after all. Switching between float and integer pretty much flushes the whole pipeline