# Why is there no floating point intrinsic for `PSHUFD` instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, vectorization, sse, intrinsics

The task I'm facing is to shuffle **one** `_m128` vector and store the result in the other one.

The way I see it, there are two basic ways to shuffle a packed floating point `_m128` vector:

- `_mm_shuffle_ps`, which uses `SHUFPS` instruction that is not necessarily the best option if you want the values from one vector only: it takes two values from the destination operand, which implies an extra move.
- `_mm_shuffle_epi32`, which uses `PSHUFD` instruction that seems to do exactly what is expected here and can have better latency/throughput than `SHUFPS`.

The latter intrinsic however works with integer vectors (`_m128i`) and there seems to be no floating point counterpart, so using it with `_m128` would require some ugly explicit casting. Also the fact that there is no such counterpart probably means that there is some proper reason for that, which I am not aware of.

The question is why is there no intrinsic to shuffle one floating point vector and store the result in another?
If `_mm_shuffle_ps(x,x, ...)` can generate `PSHUFPD`, can it be guaranteed?
If `PSHUFD` should not be used for floating point values, what is the reason for that?

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to be some mismatch between the title and the rest of the question, btw `_mm_shuffle_pd` does exist

Comment: @harold as far as I know `_mm_shuffle_pd` shuffles double-precision floats (`_m128d`) and it still takes them from 2 vectors

Comment: What's wrong with doing `__m128 y = _mm_shuffle_ps(x, x, shuf_mask);`? Shuffles are very fast; there's no performance gain to be made by them only taking one input. If the look of the code bothers you, then you can write an inline wrapper function or macro. AVX introduced `_mm_permute_ps()`, which takes one input as you're looking for.

Comment: @JasonR nothing, but it will result in (possibly) slower `SHUFPS` instruction, so I ask if there is a specific reason for that

Comment: I've never seen a compiler generate the `PSHUFD` instruction from a  `_mm_shuffle_ps()` call. Can you provide an example? Also, according to [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide), the two instructions have the same throughput and latency on all recent architectures (barring any bypass delays from moving between FP and integer domains).

Comment: @JasonR my bad, I meant `SHUFPS`. `PSHUFD` is what I'd like to have here:)

Comment: Why do you want `PSHUFD`? You haven't cited any verifiable reason for why you believe it's better. It's actually likely to be slower due to domain crossing in the SIMD unit.

Comment: I believe `PSHUFD` may very well be slower due to domain crossing, but `SHUFPS` takes two values from the output register, I think this can result in an extra move. Anyway, the domain crossing thing could be an actual anwer for me here, can you give me some reference on that?

Comment: On affected processors, the "domain crossing" problem is a *way* bigger deal, performance-wise, than any infinitesimal penalty you'd see from taking two values from the output register. If you want to avoid any sort of penalty, just use registers for all of the operands. It seems you are trying to solve an invented problem. What measurements are you using that are telling you `PSHUFD` is faster than `SHUFPS`? As for the reference you asked for, the definitive one is [Agner Fog's online resources](http://agner.org/optimize/). See pp. 112 & 129 on http://agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you very much for the reference, I'm fine with taking two values from the output register, but we have to put them there first, right?:)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you're trying to do, but you can use the same register for both source and destination operands with SHUFPD.

Comment: Well your title suggests `shufpd`, that's why I mentioned the corresponding intrinsic. It doesn't fit with the rest of your post. Btw with VEX encoding the inherent destructive nature of a `shufps` (which can cause an extra move to be inserted sometimes) goes away so even though it was a problem I would say it isn't one now

Comment: @CodyGray OK at this point you've completely answered my question, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrinsics are supposed to map one-to-one with instructions. It would be very undesirable for _mm_shuffle_ps to generate PSHUFD. It should always generate SHUFPS. The documentation does not suggest that there is a case where it would do otherwise.

There is a performance penalty on certain processors when data is cast to single- or double-precision floating-point. This is because the processor augments the SSE registers with internal registers containing the FP classification of the data, e.g. zero or NaN or infinity or normal. When switching types you incur a stall as it performs that step. I don't know if this is still true of modern processors, but you can consult the Intel Architecture Optimization manuals for that information.

SHUFPS is not significantly slower than PSHUFD on modern processors. According to Agner Fog's instruction tables (http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), they have identical latency and throughput on Haswell (4th gen. Core i7). On Nehalem (1st gen. Core i7), they have identical latency, but PSHUFD has a throughput of 2/cycle and SHUFPS has a throughput of 1/cycle. So, you cannot say that one instruction should be preferred over the other across all processors, even if you ignore the performance penalty associated with switching types.

There is also a way to cast between __m128, __m128d, and __m128i: _mm_castXX_YY (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/695375?language=es) where XX and YY are each one of ps, pd, or si128. For example, _mm_castps_pd(). This is really a bad idea because the processors on which PSHUFD is faster suffer from the performance penalty associated with switching back to FP afterward. In other words, there is no faster way to do a SHUFPS other than doing a SHUFPS.

Comment: The benefit to `pshufd` is that it's a copy-and-shuffle.  If the original input is still needed later, `pshufd` avoids a `movaps` instruction to copy the register for `shufps` to modify in-place.  The actually reason *not* to use it isn't a stall of any pipeline, it's bypass latency between SIMD-integer and FP forwarding networks: 2 cycles each way on Nehalem, non-existent for shuffles on Sandybridge-family.  (Not FP format info; you're mixing it up with an AMD-specific float-vs-double big penalty, and 1 cycle lower latency when an add/mul/fma instruction consumes the result of the same unit)

Comment: See Agner Fog's microarch pdf for details on bypass latency, and on that AMD effect.